# How to cover room in light with least number of light sources?

Tags: python, image-processing, geometry

I have an image of a map of room.
and I want to calculate minimum point in this map that I can set a lamp. that all of my map have light.
I read image and edge detect.
but I don't know how can I calculate number of lamp.
have python a function for this?

Fro example:
[image]

and answer: 2

[image]

Comment: that is not an AI problem. that's a geometry problem, i.e. computer graphics.

Comment: Yeah, this question is probably a better fit for the math stack exchange. As a primer, think about how you can figure out if a corner on a polygon is convex or concave. If there is a single concave corner, where are all the places in the polygon that you can place a light that can reach all the other corners? How does that theory extend to a shape with two concave corners? These should be all the general milestones you need to answer the larger problem. This sounds like homework so I don't want to answer further than that.

Comment: I wish there were a *computer*-graphics or *computational*-geometry tag. "geometry" is covers the area well enough but "graphics" (visual art?) really doesn't express the concept of *computer graphics* (geometry, geometry processing, polygons, meshes, ...)